# Get last day of previous quarter

Tags: vba, excel

```
DateAdd("m", -(Month(Date) - 1) Mod 3 - 1, Date)
```

This gives me `6/28/2015` while I need `20150630` . I can work on the format part but don't know how to get the last day of previous quarter instead of today's date of last quarter.

Comment: Instead of finding out the month of the previous quarter, find the 1st month of the current quarter and create a date (with `DateSerial`) with the found year and month but using day `1`. Then subtract `1` day from it.

Comment: Ah crap I did it with a formula, but this might work: `=EOMONTH(NOW(),MOD(-MONTH(NOW()),3)-3)`, you can substitute `NOW()` with whatever date you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for VBA. It just determines the first day of the current quarter and then subtracts one day.

```
Debug.Print DateAdd("q", DatePart("q", Date) - 1, "1/1/" & Year(Date)) - 1
```